# iOS Internal testing - Unable to download crash information?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I have recently uploaded my app to the App Store for internal testing (TestFlight, iOS 8). I am currently the only tester. When I test using TestFlight, my app crashes; however, the same operation works fine when debugging from Xcode.

My understanding is that a crash log should be generated and I should be able to see crash logs in Xcode's Organizer. However, when I attempt to download crash logs in Organizer, it says there are no crash logs. There is also a triangle with an exclamation point symbol. When I click on that, I get an error pop up with a 'try again' button that says:

> **Unable to download crash information.**
>   An error occurred preventing Xcode from downloading updated crash information. Please try again later.

Trying again does no good. I'm running Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).

-------------------- UPDATE 7/29/2015 -----------------

No luck. I'm still not receiving logs. The crashes are now hard for me to reproduce and my beta audience is unfortunately small. I am certain I am checking the option to send symbols with the archive, by the way.

I'm going to look into 3rd party crash solutions. My app is for special needs folks and not intended for sale, so cost will be a factor. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the response I received from App Store Developer support:

> Thank for contacting App Store Developer Support regarding your app, Angelshare.
>
> I understand you have discovered your app is crashing during beta testing, but you are not able to access crash reports in iTunes Connect to diagnose the issue.
>
> If there is insufficient data for a report to be generated, the tab will be blank. This does not indicate a problem with your iTunes Connect account or with the report system. There are many potential causes of insufficient data. If the report covers a newly released app  version or a newly released version of the iOS, then little time may have elapsed before the report was generated for diagnostic logs to be received. Also, various factors can reduce the amount of available data. Logs are submitted only by users who opt in to send diagnostic data to Apple, and statistical sampling techniques are applied to the submitted data.
>
> For more information, please refer to the iTunes Connect Developer Guide:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iTunesConnectGuide
>
> Also review the iTunes Connect FAQ for additional information about crash reports:
>
> https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=faqIndex&group=applicationcrashlogs
>
> If you have any other questions, please use the Contact Us section in iTunes Connect:
>
> http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus

Comment: Has someone found out anything yet? Could this maybe has got something to do with missing symbols at exporting the app?

Comment: Still no response.  I think I'm going to have to use one of my Apple developer support instances. I've gone through several builds and the app is in beta testing through TestFlight and still no crash logs. I don't think there's a symbol file issue, but I think even if there was, I should get non-symbolificated crash logs.

Comment: I have the same problem here. I always send symbols alongside the app. @psparago please let us know if you get a response on this issue.

Comment: Update 8/1/2015 - My app uses Parse and I realized yesterday that Parse has a Crash Reporting feature, so I'm using that for now. The test crash I did this morning worked. We'll see ...

Comment: Can anyone help ? I'm currently testing an app via testflight and no crash reported in the Xcode organizer. Also what I don't get is that in the crash section of the organiser it only show some builds but not all..

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Upload symbols checked, multiple versions through Apple TestFlight internal testing, crashes reported by users but none in the Organizer "Crashes" tab.

Comment: @Sean, and Robert, this is really annoying. Apple sort of brushed it off. I'm disappointed. If anyone has better luck, please update this thread.

Comment: I don't think you've done anything wrong in your setup. It seems that Apple's system just becomes unavailable for days at a time. I'll check one day and have lots of logs for all my app versions, then another day all I see is that error message for all app versions. Clearly that error message is indicating a different problem than "insufficient data for a report to be generated." It only works about half the time for me.

Comment: Are you sure your app is actually crashing and not _hanging_ (and then being killed by iOS)?  I believe the latter does not generate crash reports in TestFlight.  (In any event, I understand this doesn't explain the "unable to download" message.)

Comment: Thank you Turix. As I'm sure you're aware, this information is often second hand, but I'm told that the app disappeared which I think is solid evidence that it was "crashing". I've never received an error log from Apple. I did implement Parse.com's alternative (which is now being deprecated) and I do get crash logs (I tested this by causing a crash). I'm at a loss as to why my app does not receive crash logs and, unfortunately, no one I've reached out to at Apple seems to care.

Comment: Hanging apps often appear similar to a crash (since they get killed by iOS if they are unresponsive), but their death is just slightly delayed. Having said that, your crash test sounds conclusive (that XCode did not get the report, but Parse did). FWIW, I use TestFairy for beta testing my Android apps and like the diagnostics I get about crashes from them. Although I've never needed it for iOS, they apparently work there too. Re Apple, I once was able to get through to them via submitting feedback in iTunes Connect.  I got an email back from devprograms@apple.com. It wasn't helpful though! :|

Comment: You can use HockeyApp for logging your beta version crashes. (you have to upload the dSYM file of the same ipa to see the log details)

Comment: Try in mac os Console, once you've paired your device to Xcode, to would show all logs there.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but if someone else is still facing this issue, make sure your device has the switch in Settings > Privacy > Analytics > Share iPhone Analytics, turned on.

Answer (score 3):

You can find them on a crashed device:
**Settings > Privacy > Analytics & Improvements > Analytics Data >** (search for your bundle ID among the other listed logs)

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only tester (and so always have access to the device on which the crash occured), then you can bypass Xcode and instead use a tool from the following library:

http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

What the library does is provide a variety of different tools that lets you interact with your IOS device natively from a terminal shell. It's got a load of useful features you should explore, but, for your purposes 'idevicecrashreport' is what you need.

You run this from your command line and you can export your crash logs directly from your device to your machine.

Installation instructions for OSX here: http://brewformulas.org/Libimobiledevice

Once installed, pair your device with your machine, go to your terminal and type in:

> idevicecrashreport

the -e flag allows you to specify a location to dump your logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the third party API named crashlytics. This shows you the crash logs and sends the daily reports of your app also you can see the analytics. Here you can find the documentation https://try.crashlytics.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a crash device you can get the crash log using Xcode.

Go to Window-> Devices and simulator -> SELECT Your Device -> tap on View Device Logs.

In device log, you can see all the crashes occurred in your device. Based on the crash time you can identify your app crash log.

[image]